# Joining tables in SQL with out commmon field

Tags: mysql

I have Three tables in my Project. I have to Insert values from each table into database. And also I don't have any common field in between tables. Now I want to get the output with all fields from three tables in One table. Please help me..

Comment: Would you like to add sample data from the 3 tables together with your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a join table that links these three tables. Consider three tables
Table1
Table2
Table3

Each table has an ID. Your fourth table (join_table) will then have three fields such as
id, table_1_id, table_2_id, table_3_id.

Now you can create the join between the three tables by referencing the ID on each of the tables and inserting the values into the fourth table

```
    insert into join_table values (<table_1_id>, <table_2_id>, <table_3_id>).
```

You can then show all fields across all tables by joining all three tables using the following

```
    select table_1*, table_2*, table_3* from table_1 
    join on table_1.id = join_table.table_1_id
    join on table_2.id = join_table.table_2_id
    join on table_3.id = join_table.table_3_id
```

This will give you a result showing all data from the three tables